# one-point-compactification of a Polish space is a Polish space?

Tags: general-topology, markov-process

Is it true that the one-point-compactification of a Polish space is again a Polish space? I am currently learning something about Feller Processes and I think at some point this is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true: if a Polish space $X$ is locally compact then $\alpha X$ will be compact Hausdorff and as $X$ is separable (and thus second countable), the same holds for $\alpha X$, and a second countable compact Hausdorff space is Polish.

For a non-locally compact Polish space, $\alpha X$ will not even be Hausdorff, let alone Polish.